# What is the physically significance of having trace less than 1 in squared mixed state density matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator, quantum-states, trace

I was going through density matrices where I get to know that the trace of squared mixed state density matrix is less than a pure state density matrix. I also went through the proof. But I want to know what does having a trace less than 1 (for squared mixed state density matrix) means physically? Or is it just a mathematical condition?

Comment: *[...] that the trace of a mixed state density matrix is less than a pure state density matrix* - this is not true. Did you mean "squared" matrices instead?

Comment: For density matrices you always have trace 1. This is the condition that the sum over all probabilities to measure a particle in a certain state is 1.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I am extremely sorry. I am gonna edit this. Yes, I wanted to ask why does the trace of squared mixed density matrices are less than 1? What does it signify physically?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This is a completely legit question to ask.

Comment: @ThomasTappeiner thanks for explaining this to me. But when the mixed density matrix is squared, it's trace value is less than 1. What doesn't that physically mean?

Comment: You should also edit the title accordingly.

Comment: @TobiasFünke A badly written or unclear question is a legit reason for downvotes. And after reading the title, the question body is *still* unclear (as one already assumes the trace referes to the density matrix itself).

Comment: @SoumyadeepChakraborty Do you understand the general meaning of a (mixed) density matrix?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purity_(quantum_mechanics)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The density matrix of a *pure* state is a projection operator $\rho_\psi= |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$, ($\langle \psi |\psi \rangle=1$) with $\rho_\psi^2 = \rho_\psi = \rho_\psi^\dagger$ and consequently ${\rm Tr} \rho_\psi^2 = {\rm Tr} \rho_\psi =1$.

In the *general* case, a density matrix $\rho$ is characterized by the properties $\rho^\dagger = \rho \ge 0$ and ${\rm Tr}\rho=1$. Its spectral representation is given by $\rho =\sum_n p_n |\phi_n\rangle \langle \phi_n |$, where $\{|\phi_n \rangle\}_n$ is an orthonormal basis and the eigenvalues $0 \le p_n \le 1$ are probabilities with the normalization condition ${\rm Tr} \rho = \sum_n p_n=1$. The trace of $\rho^2$ is thus given by ${\rm Tr} \rho^2 =\sum_n p_n^2 \le 1$, where the equality sign holds if and only if $p_m=1$ for some index $m$ and $p_n=0$ for $n\ne m$.

In other words, the value of ${\rm Tr} \rho^2$ allows to distinguish pure states (with ${\rm Tr} \rho^2 =1$) from proper mixed states (with ${\rm Tr} \rho^2 <1$).

Comment: Thanks for explaining

Comment: @SoumyadeepChakraborty If you think this answer was helpful and answered your question, consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. If not, you should clarify which part of your question the answer did not address.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thanks for helping me. I am new to stack exchange community. If I did anything rude or troublesome, I am extreme sorry. I am trying to learn the etiquettes required here.